# What is 'Closure' in Functions?

Tags: dart, closures

I am right now learning a beautiful programming language, Dart, which I am loving so much. However, I am finding my basic programming knowledge has some gaps, and one of them is 'Closure' in Functions which I am finding difficult to understand. Can you please explain to me what is unique from Anonymous Function??

Answer (score 4):

"Closure" is a word that is used about many different things.

Generally, and originally, a closure is a (function) value which contains references to variables (it "closes over" those variables).

In Dart, you can introduce functions in two different ways.

- A function *declaration*: `int foo(int x) => x;` (as a top-level, static - if prefixed by `static`, instance or local function).
- A function *expression*: `(int x) => x` (as an expression).

The first function is *named*, and can be called by name, referring directly to the declaration (`foo(42)`).
It can also be turned into a function *value* by "tearing off" the function:

```dart
int Function(int) f = foo;
```

A function expression evaluates to a function value directly.

```dart
int Function(int) f = (int x) => x;
```

A lot of people use the word "closure" about *function values*, also called "first class function values" because they are objects like any other object, not special second-class values that can only be used in limited ways.
If you see someone saying "closure", assume that's what they mean - an *object* which is also a *function*.

Technically, the function values here do not close over any variables.
An example of one which does would be:

```dart
int Function(int) adder(int base) => (int addition) => base + addition;
int Function(int) add2 = adder(2);
```

The function value stored in the `add2` variable here is the value of the function expression `(int addition) => base + addition`. The `base` variable is not bound by this expression, it is instead *captured*/"closed over" by the closure/function value. The `base` variable being closed over here comes from the invocation of `adder` with the value `2`.